# Image in literal-block

Tags: python-sphinx

I'm trying to have a directory representation in my documentation that has images to indicate when something is a folder. Currently I'm using the literal-block to get the nice monospaced fonts but that does not allow me to place images. What is the correct way?

RST:

```
Look at these folders::

projects
└─ BigBang
    ├─ |folder_img| tests
    ├─ |folder_img| docs
    ├─ |folder_img| src
    ├─ __init__.py
    └─ listing.xml

.. |folder_img| image:: _static/folder.svg
   :height: 10px
```

But of course instead of a nice image of the folder I only see the `|folder_img|` text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with the [parsed-literal](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#parsed-literal-block) directive.

```
.. parsed-literal::

   projects
   └─ BigBang
       ├─ |folder_img| tests
       ├─ |folder_img| docs
       ├─ |folder_img| src
       ├─ __init__.py
       └─ listing.xml

.. |folder_img| image:: _static/folder.svg
   :height: 10px
```